# How to validate wysiwyg editor using bootstrap validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-wysiwyg, bootstrapvalidator

Using

> bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower 2013-11-22 (WYSIWYG Editor)

and

> BootstrapValidator v0.5.2

Validate textarea(bootstrap-wysihtml5 editor) using bootstrap validation. Just need to check **NotEmpty** and **Max Characters** then submit Form.

So far tried

```js
$('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator({
  message: 'This value is not valid',
  feedbackIcons: {
    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
  },
  ignore: ":hidden:not(textarea)",
  fields: {
    policyta: {
      group: '.lnbrd',
      validators: {
        notEmpty: {
          message: 'Textarea cannot be empty'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}).on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $form = $("#setpolicyform"),
    $url = $form.attr('action');
  $.post($url, $form.serialize()).done(function(dte) {
    $("#policy-content").html(dte);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="POST" action="self.php" name="setpolicyform" id="setpolicyform">
  <div class='box-body pad'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="lnbrd">
        <textarea class="form-control textarea" name="policyta" placeholder="Place some text here" style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-footer clearfix">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" id="setpolicyformsubmitbtn"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>&nbsp;SAVE</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v6s0726L/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/v6s0726L/1/)

Comment: I'm lost.  From what I can see that wysiwyg tool is less than worthless.  Perhaps I'm doing it wrong. Not sure why you even thought to mention it.  And the code snippet thing too seems to be not worth much.  How about a simple JS fiddle showing us what you've tried.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what tool you are using. For bootstrapvalidator() I'm seeing `This repository is for anyone who still use the BootstrapValidator.  

It's no longer supported.  

Please upgrade to use FormValidation.`   http://formvalidation.io/

Comment: @zipzit find JS Fiddle in Question(Updated). I'm using core php(no tools). its an update(part) for my client project(not doing from scratch). thanks for trying to understand issue.

Comment: @zipzit i need to check textarea 'not Empty' before form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to validate the `WYSIWYG Editor`, reason `bootstrapValidator` not validating it because after initializing `WYSIWYG Editor` on textarea `name="policyta"`, it will be hidden and ignored by `bootstrapValidator`

So the one way is do not hide the `textarea`, just set `z-index: -1` and it will go behind the `WYSIWYG Editor`, use `WYSIWYG Editor` [event](https://github.com/Waxolunist/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-bower#events) `load` to add the CSS after initializing,

CSS

```
.textnothide {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JS

```
$('.textarea').wysihtml5({
    events: {
        load: function () {
            $('.textarea').addClass('textnothide');
        }
    }
});
```

Now let's validate the textarea with `bootstrapValidator` and you also asked for `Max Characters` limit

First `bootstrapValidator` script

```
$('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator({
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    //ignore: ":hidden:not(textarea)", //<---- No Need of This
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        policyta: {
            group: '.lnbrd',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'Textarea cannot be empty'
                },
                stringLength: { //<- Limit Maximum Character(s)
                    max: 50,
                    message: 'Maximum 50 Characters Required'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now let's check and validate the textarea with `bootstrapValidator`, need another `wysihtml5` event `change` to check the changes and re-validate

```
change: function () {
    $('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'policyta');
}
```

So the Final Script will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid'
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            policyta: {
                group: '.lnbrd',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Textarea cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 50,
                        message: 'Maximum 50 Characters Required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $('.textarea').wysihtml5({
        events: {
            load: function () {
                $('.textarea').addClass('textnothide');
            },
            change: function () {
                $('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'policyta');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wu5oLvLf/1/)

Comment: keep the button enable `$('#setpolicyform').bootstrapValidator({// validation code}).on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {if (data.bv.getSubmitButton()) {data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);}});`

Answer (score 2):

Folks, bootstrapValidator has been upgraded to formValidation. If you are using the updated version of formValidation you can do this instead of adding a separate class to hide the text area:

```
   $('#setpolicyform').formValidation({
                                framework: 'bootstrap',
                                excluded: [':disabled'], /* This will do the trick of validating for notEmpty*/
                                icon : {
                                    valid : '',
                                    invalid : '',
                                    validating : 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                                },
                                fields: {
                                 policyta: {
                                  group: '.lnbrd',
                                  validators: {
                                   notEmpty: {
                                   message: 'Textarea cannot be empty'
                                   },
                                   stringLength: {
                                    max: 50,
                                   message: 'Maximum 50 Characters Required'
                               }
                            }
                         }
                      }
        });

$('.textarea').wysihtml5({
        events: {
            change: function () {
                $('#setpolicyform').formValidation('revalidateField', 'policyta');
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks