# laravel-jsvalidation package not supporting for wysiwyg editor

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I'm using a wysiwyg editor ([bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://bootstrap-wysiwyg.github.io/bootstrap3-wysiwyg/)) inside a laravel form instead of a text area. And I'm using [laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation) to validate the form. But unfortunately front end validation is not happening for my wysiwyg editor field.

This is my text area code.

```
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('App\Http\Requests\MyFormRequest') !!}

<input type='text' name='title' />
<textarea name='content' class="textarea" placeholder="Enter text ..." 
style="width: 100%; height: 200px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 18px;"></textarea>

<script>
  $('.textarea').wysihtml5();
<script>
```

I use Form Requests to validate this and this is my request class.

```
class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest {

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            "title" => "required",
            "content" => "required",
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Title field is perfectly validating but not the content field in js validation**. It would be a great help if someone knows how to do it. (No errors are appearing too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time of checking I found out the issue. it's the same issue like this link
- [How to validate wysiwyg editor using bootstrap validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821071/how-to-validate-wysiwyg-editor-using-bootstrap-validation)

This happens WYSIWYG Editor hides the textarea and **jquery validation** related laravel-jsvalidation not working with hidden fields. So we need to change the code like,

CSS

```
.textnothide {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

JS

```
<script>
  $('.textarea').wysihtml5(
      events: {
        load: function () {
            $('.textarea').addClass('textnothide');
        }
    }
  );
<script>
```

Hope this question is not a duplicate since it's related to **laravel-jsvalidation** and keeping the answer in case anyone else has the same issue.